inserting icon and text into bubble chat in flutter
I want to insert icons and text into the chat bubble in Flutter, but using rows in the syntax actually makes the bubble wider.
I just want to make the text and icon in the right position, and also make the bubble shape follow the amount of text, not expand like that
this is my code and the result
Bubble(
            margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 10),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            nip: BubbleNip.rightTop,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 255, 199, 1.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text("Bang kuy, adu bola sama rt beside"),
                Icon(Icons.done_all)
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          )

the result

Rather then using IntrinsicWidth widget. Try giving Row mainAxisSize as MainAxisSize.min. Then the row will only take content width rather then using whole horizontal space.

Try below code with IntrinsicWidth...
        Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: Bubble(
                      margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 10),
                      nip: BubbleNip.rightTop,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 255, 199, 1.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [Text("Bang kuy, adu bola sama rt beside"), Icon(Icons.done_all)],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: Bubble(
                      margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 10),
                      nip: BubbleNip.leftTop,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 255, 199, 1.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [Text("Bang kuy, adu bola sama rt beside"), Icon(Icons.done_all)],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

